# Android media player\video issue (First video get frozen when i play 2nd)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am working on an android based application, that play videos. when i play any video it starts it then i press the back button and go to back screen to select another one to play(with-out stopping the first video) when i select the second video the first video (that was already playing) get frozen and second video get started behind this first video, i can listen the music etc of the second video, can any one help how that how to stop and remove the video from media player so that user may watch the new video 
Here is my activity

```
public class TrailVideoActivity extends Activity implements
OnBufferingUpdateListener, OnCompletionListener,
OnPreparedListener, OnVideoSizeChangedListener, SurfaceHolder.Callback{ 
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyMediaPlayer");
        //setContentView(R.layout.main);

        setContentView(LayoutInflater.from(getParent()).inflate(R.layout.trial_video_player, null));


        mPreview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
        holder = mPreview.getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
        holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    }
private void playMediaPlayerVideo() {
        Log.d(TAG, "playMediaPlayerVideo called");
        doCleanUp();
        try {
            if (videoURL == "") {
                // Tell the user to provide a media file URL.
                Toast.makeText(this,"Please edit MediaPlayerDemo_Video Activity,"
                        + " and set the path variable to your media file URL.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } 
            Log.d("TrailVideoActivity", videoURL);
            // Create a new media player and set the listeners
            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(videoURL);
            mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
            mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
            //mMediaPlayer.setVideoQuality(MediaPlayer.VIDEOQUALITY_HIGH);
            //mMediaPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
            //mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
            mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(2);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer arg0, int percent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBufferingUpdate percent:" + percent);

    }

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCompletion called");
    }

    public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {
        Log.v(TAG, "onVideoSizeChanged called");
        if (width == 0 || height == 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "invalid video width(" + width + ") or height(" + height + ")");
            return;
        }
        mIsVideoSizeKnown = true;
        mVideoWidth = width;
        mVideoHeight = height;
        if (mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed && mIsVideoSizeKnown) {
            startVideoPlayback();
        }
    }

    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaplayer) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPrepared called");
        mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed = true;
        if (mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed && mIsVideoSizeKnown) {
            startVideoPlayback();
        }
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceholder, int i, int j, int k) {
        Log.d(TAG, "surfaceChanged called");

    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceholder) {
        Log.d(TAG, "surfaceDestroyed called");
    }


    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.d(TAG, "surfaceCreated called");
        playMediaPlayerVideo();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPause called");
        super.onPause();
        releaseMediaPlayer();
        doCleanUp();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy called");
        super.onDestroy();
        releaseMediaPlayer();
        doCleanUp();
    }

    private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
        Log.d(TAG, "releaseMediaPlayer called");
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            mMediaPlayer.release();
            mMediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }

    private void doCleanUp() {
        Log.d(TAG, "doCleanUp called");
        mVideoWidth = 0;
        mVideoHeight = 0;
        mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed = false;
        mIsVideoSizeKnown = false;

    }

    private void startVideoPlayback() {
        Log.v(TAG, "startVideoPlayback");
        holder.setFixedSize(mVideoWidth, mVideoHeight);
        /*holder.setKeepScreenOn(false);
        holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);*/
        mMediaPlayer.start();
        app.dismissDialog();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think u can call `MediaPlayer` `release()` method in ur `surfaceDestroyed` method also like below

```
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceholder) {
    Log.d(TAG, "surfaceDestroyed called");
     if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
        mMediaPlayer.release();
        mMediaPlayer = null;
    }
}
```

Also u can release `MediaPlayer` in `OnBackPressed`

Can u check if this works...